# Not each subgroup $H\subset G$ can be the kernel of a homomorphism

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

My book says that each subgroup $H\subset G$ can be the image of a homomorphism; consider the inclusion mapping $f\colon H\to G\colon x\mapsto x.$ However, not each subgroup can be the kernel of a homomorphism.

I don't see why this should be a problem. Consider $H\subset G$ a subgroup. We know that $H$ is not empty. Now consider the mapping $f\colon H\to G:x\mapsto e$. This way, $H$ is the kernel of $f$, and $f$ is a homomorphism, because $f(a+b)=e=e+e=f(a)+f(b)$.

So why did they say that not each subgroup can be the kernel of a homomorphism?

Comment: They meant a kernel of a homomorphism with domain $G$.

Comment: Then we do they consider the inclusion mapping, that also doesn't have domain $G$? @MatheiBoulomenos

Comment: The assertion means not each subgroup of a group $\color{red}G$ is the kernel of a homomorphism *from*  $\color{red}G$ to another group.

Comment: The inclusion mapping has domain $H$.

Comment: @Bernard Exactly, why can we have domain $H$ for the assertion that each image can be $H$, however, when we talk about the kernel, we need $G$ to be the domain?

Comment: It's only that your phrasing is not complete: it should begin with `Let $G$ be group. […]` . So we know the assertion is about a group (named $G$ in the assertion, but that is unimportant), which is the domain of a homomorphism. When you speak of the inclusion morphism $H\subset G$, the domain is $H$ by definition, that's all. And indeed, you observe $H$ is the kernel of a homomorphism with domain $H$.

Comment: @ShaVuklia When you consider the image, the correct analogue is to ask for *co*domain $H,$ which is what the inclusion has.

Comment: @RCT Yes, got it! I wasn't aware of these rules. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is meant is that there does not exist a homomorphism $f:G\rightarrow K$ such that $\text{ker } f = H$. In fact, such an $f$ exists iff $H$ is [normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_subgroup). To see this, note that the kernel of a homomorphism is a normal subgroup. Conversely, if $H$ is normal, one can take the canonical projection $G\rightarrow G/H$.